# I need to extract the Hours or timings data from the drop down

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to extract Hours data from the drop-down menu from a Facebook page. I have tried to select its CSS selectors I can fetch the timings data but it is not coming in aligned

Output:

Hours
Hours
Closed now
Monday
CLOSED
Tuesday
16:00 - 23:00
Wednesday
CLOSED
Thursday
16:00 - 23:00
Friday
11:30 - 23:59
Saturday
11:00 - 00:00
Sunday
11:00 - 23:00
Popular times
MON
TUE
WED
THU
FRI
SAT
SUN
6AM
9AM
12PM
3PM
6PM
9PM
12AM
3AM
Services
Outdoor seating
Roadside collection
In-store collection\

I want it to be like this

Hours Monday CLOSED Tuesday 16:00 - 23:00 Wednesday CLOSED Thursday 16:00 - 23:00 Friday 11:30 - 23:59 Saturday 11:00 - 00:00 Sunday 11:00 - 23:00

facebook url is : https://www.facebook.com/theanchorvenice/

```
span_xpath = "//span[contains(@class, 'x1q0g3np') and contains(@class, 'xohu8s8')]"
span_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, span_xpath)
button_inside_span = span_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'i')
button_inside_span.click()
hours = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@aria-label="Hours"]'))).text
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use selector that corresponding root of hours block

```js
selector = "//span[contains(@class, 'x1q0g3np') and contains(@class, 'xohu8s8')]//i"
button_inside_span = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, selector)
button_inside_span.click()
hours = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class*='xyorhqc xh8yej3']"))).text
```

(I think, you don't care about Hours label in this case and don't need it, so I used selector from open hours block).

If you need to print it in one line, you can just execute

`result = re.sub(os.linesep, ' ', hours)`